# Nested loop low perfomance

Tags: image, for-loop, nested-loops

I need to iterate through a number of images( around 3k) and make some matrix calculations. For each image this code takes nearly 10s to finish, is there any better way to avoid nested for loop in order to make it run faster? Thank you.

```
for i in range(depth.shape[0]):
 for j in range(depth.shape[1]):
    if depth[i ,j]<50:
        pixels=np.array([[i],[j],[1]])
        M=np.dot(depth[i,j],C_inv)
        M1=np.matmul(M,pixels)
```

Comment: Can you clarify/correct your code indentation to actually make your for loops nested.

Comment: Sorry for the mistake, the indentation is changed